# how to send data using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, forms, validation, send

I've just finished validating my forms which i found a tutorial using jquery. The only thing missing is sending the data to appropriate address. How do i do that?

**This is a sample of my HTML code for the forms**

```
<form id="register-form">

         <div class="four columns alpha contact-form">

         <label>prefix</label>
         <input type="text"  />
         <label><span class="asterisk">*</span>first name</label>
         <input type="text" name="firstname"/>
         <label><span class="asterisk">*</span>middle name</label>
         <input type="text" name="middlename"/>
         <label><span class="asterisk">*</span>last name</label>
         <input type="text" name="lastname"/>
         <label><span class="asterisk">*</span>email address</label>
         <input type="text" name="email"/>

        </div>
     </form>
```

**Here is the Jquery in order to validate the data in my forms.**

/*
       Basic jQuery Validation Form Demo Code
       Copyright Sam Deering 2012
       Licence: http://www.jquery4u.com/license/
*/

```
(function($,W,D)
{
var JQUERY4U = {};

JQUERY4U.UTIL =
{
    setupFormValidation: function()
    {
        //form validation rules
        $("#register-form").validate({
            rules: {
                firstname: "required",
                middlename: "required",
                lastname: "required",
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                zip: "required",
                city: "required",
                subject: "required",
                message: "required",

                agree: "required"
            },
            messages: {
                firstname: "Please enter your first name",
                middlename: "Please enter your middle name",
                lastname: "Please enter your last name",
                email: "Please enter a valid email address",
                zip: "Please enter your zip code",
                city: "Please state your city",
                subject: "Please state your inquiry",
                message:"Please include a short message"

            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                form.submit();
            }
        });
    }
}

//when the dom has loaded setup form validation rules
$(D).ready(function($) {
    JQUERY4U.UTIL.setupFormValidation();
});

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

I'm not yet adept in jquery and at the moment i'm still learning. I've read that i need to use this .serialize() in order to the data. Not sure if i'm correct

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use [serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) for sending form data to your script via [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) like this

```
$.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "yourScript.php",
         data: $('#register-form').serialize(),
         success: function(html){
            //do something
         }
       });
```

You can write that inside your `submitHandler` function

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
                    $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      url: "yourScript.php",
                      data: $('#register-form').serialize(),
                      success: function(html){
                        //do something
                      }
                    });
                    return false;
                }
```

Comment: Do i need to create another js file. One is for validation and the other is for sending data? or i can just compile them in one file?

Comment: Question the url you inserted in the code, is it possible to replace it with an email address instead of a PHP file? I'm watching a tutorial wherein the data is sent to a php file and obtain by using if(isset [POST] or something like that

Comment: The data or value i want to pass is not going to a PHP but to an email address. Sorry if i did not state my objectives very clearly. I tried replaced the comment(do something) with an alert but it doesn't seem to be working properly hmmmm

Comment: You need to send the data to the script and than you can email it from there. `success` function means when your script will be finished executing you can either show success message to the user or you can perform other tasks as you wish

Answer (score 1):

AJAX can send the data to a certain address, (a PHP file in case you want to send it to an SQL database or something)

```
$("#buttonID").click(function(){ $.ajax({ url: "<something.com/file.php";, data: {username: $(username).val()}, type: "post", success: function(msg){ }); });
```

Comment: This also does it dynamically, without having to leave the page to input the data to a database

Answer (score 0):

Dude, you do not have 'submit button' and there are some form attributes missing, atleast the form tag should be like this:

```
<form id="register-form" name="register-form" action="" method='post'>
```

action should be the URL of a server script

Comment: The code is only sample or a part. I have already placed a submit button in my codes

Answer (score 0):

To send data to appropriate address, You have to post data to an address either using [normal post](http://mrarrowhead.com/index.php?page=php_passing_variables.php) or using [ajax](http://www.phptutorialforbeginners.com/2013/01/jquery-ajax-tutorial-and-example-of.html)